# Lock wxframe position

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want my application to be locked at one position on display and dont allow it to move. The application is written with WxWidgets.

I am using wxwidgets 2.8.12 and gcc4.7 mingw on Windows 7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the move and size events.

Something like this:

```
void MyFrame::OnMove(wxMoveEvent&  )
{
  // set position back to where you want to keep it
    SetSize(x, y, wxDefaultCoord, wxDefaultCoord, wxSIZE_USE_EXISTING);
}
void MyFrame::OnSize(wxSizeEvent&  )
{
  // set position back to where you want to keep it
    SetSize(x, y, wxDefaultCoord, wxDefaultCoord, wxSIZE_USE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: To prevent the frame from being resized it's enough to not use `wxRESIZE_BORDER` style. There is no symmetric way to prevent it from being moved though because it's a very bad idea to not allow the user to do it. I.e. the submitter shouldn't be even trying to do this in the first place.